# Is there a way to force thrift generate separate file for each class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, thrift

I have thrift file with many structs in it. For C#, thrift generates bunch of files, but for Objective C it gives me only `.h` and `.m` files. Version of thrift is 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Typically not. The way in which the Thrift compiler organizes generated sources are pretty much based on what the original developer considered being consistent with the usual way to do things in particular language. The generated code is not intended to be neatly organized or maintainable in the first run, the primary goal is performance (and of course perfectly working code).

Sorry, there is no other answer, except maybe providing a patch.